# WooCommerce programmatically created order hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

In my scenario I need to fix orders that come without shipping costs. This script works.
But it only works if orders are made on the shop-frontend!
Whenever an order is created by script/plugin, it doesn't get recognized.

Usually, I use the hook woocommerce_checkout_order_processed.
Now I found the hook save_post_shop_order, which works somehow but fires about 6x and only one time with shipping data.

**Problem: I need the correct shipping data. Many hooks I tried don't work at all or don't give me shipping details within the order data.**

**What is the correct hook for orders created with**

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
.
.
.
$order-> save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Method to create a new order in the database.
 *
 * @param WC_Order $order Order object.
 */
public function create( &$order ) {
    if ( '' === $order->get_order_key() ) {
        $order->set_order_key( wc_generate_order_key() );
    }
    parent::create( $order );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', $order->get_id(), $order );
}
```

woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php Line 80. You can use the hook `woocommerce_new_order` to achieve your requirement.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'handle_new_order_data', 10, 2 );

function handle_new_order_data( $order_id, $order ) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
}
```

Comment: TYSM for your quick reply. But with this hook unfortunately there is no shippping data:
$shipping_methods = $order->get_shipping_methods(); 
remains NULL. :(

Comment: I remember trying this hook in the very first try, and here's someone who has the same problem. This is why I switched to use woocommerce_checkout_order_processed

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/370312/woocommerce-get-items-returns-empty-array

Comment: `do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $posted_data, $order );` The second parameter in this hook contains all the form data in the checkout